# Adding Data to two Datagridviews

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I want to Add Data But I want to Put It In 2 DataGridViews. I tried this but On the 2nd Datagridview I wont Work, It Wont Add, Only In the 1st Datagridview

```
string query = "insert into dbuser.patientform (patientname,homeaddress,occupation,emailaddress,sex,age,status,birthday,cellphoneno,refferedby,date,diagnosis,treatment)"
    + "values('" + this.textBox1.Text + "','" + this.textBox2.Text + "','" + this.textBox3.Text + "','" + this.textBox4.Text + "','" + this.comboBox1.SelectedItem + "','" + this.textBox5.Text + "','" + this.comboBox2.SelectedItem + "','" + this.dateTimePicker1.Text + "','" + this.textBox6.Text + "','" + this.textBox7.Text + "','" + this.dateTimePicker2.Text + "','" + this.textBox8.Text + "','" + this.textBox9.Text + "') ;";

string quer = "insert into dbuser.patienthistory (patientname,date,diagnosis,treatment)"
+ "values('" + this.textBox1.Text + this.dateTimePicker2.Text + "','" + this.textBox8.Text + "','" + this.textBox9.Text + "') ;";


MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, condb);
MySqlCommand cm = new MySqlCommand(quer, condb);

MySqlDataReader myreader;
MySqlDataReader myreader1;
try
{  
    condb.Open();
    myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    condb.Close();

    condb.Open();
    myreader1 = cm.ExecuteReader();


    MessageBox.Show("Saved");
    textBox1.Clear();
    textBox2.Clear();
    textBox3.Clear();
    textBox4.Clear();
    comboBox1.SelectedItem = false;
    textBox5.Clear();
    comboBox2.SelectedItem = false;
    textBox6.Clear();
    textBox7.Clear();
    textBox8.Clear();
    textBox9.Clear();
    dateTimePicker1.Text = null;

    condb.Close();


    dataset = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dataset);
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();

    bs.DataSource = dataset;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
    dataGridView2.DataSource = bs;

    da.Update(dataset);
```

Comment: By the way where is `da` value is initialized ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest do followings :

1. Open and Close Connection one time if two request will use same connection string
2. Use MySqlDataAdapter for filling data to DataTable.
3. Set DataTable to DataGridView

Comment: Thanks I will try this :)